# how does webapi2 login works together with mvc5?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have a entire site built to work with webapi2. The problem comes when i need to export a file.

In modern browsers, when i make a /Token requisition passing Login and password and them calling the mvc5 method /SomeList/Export it works fine. /SomeList/Export has no especial headers and im not passing the token, i can open this in any of the browsers windows and it still works. I dont now how. Maybe a cookie or something?

the problem is that in ie8 it dosent work. I cant use mvc5 authorized actions.

how this webapi2/mvc5 works? And if it is possible, how to make it work in ie8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization works completely differently in Web Api vs MVC. They can use the same base of user accounts, but logging into Web Api, does nothing for MVC and vice versa. Each has to be authorized separately.

Comment: so how it works on chrome? I can test this using postman. I make the token request them call mvc url and it works. If i just call mvc url it dosent. Im pretty lost.

Comment: Can't tell you. All I can say is that MVC authorization is session based and Web Api is not. In fact, Web Api has no concept of a session. So, authorizing via a token in Web Api won't set the necessary cookies to be logged in with MVC any more than authorizing MVC will automatically send a token to Web Api.